# Ordering of transactions in corda

Tags: transactions, corda, notary

I have a doubt regarding the ***ordering of transactions*** by the notary in corda. For instance, if there are **two partys partyA and partyB, consuming a same input state**, sends a txn at the same time to corda, how does this work?
whether this transactions will be processed by the notary parallely or in a sequential manner?
what happens if there are multiple parties/nodes and if hitting the txn becomes higher?

Answer (score 1):

Only one transaction consuming a certain state would be processed by the notary and the other would be rejected. There is no guarantee of which one would be processed first. At the end of the day, node stores data in database tables, and whichever transaction is able to acquire lock first on the database would be processed an the other would be rejected.

Comment: How does this work in case PartyB is not available (for, say, technical failures) and so the flows are checkpointed in PartyA and retried when PartyB is on again? Do the flow start in random order?